# Can't add UIButton Outlet to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm only able to add an Action to my UIView subclass and not an Outlet. But I am able to add an Outlet to the parent controller that is holding the UIView.

[image: fig 1]

[image: fig 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add `UIButtons` to a `UIView` programatically, but there's no we to do it with an `IBOutlet`.

```
let testView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
let button = UIButton()
self.testView.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually add a IBOutlet of a button to the UIView subclass, because your UIView subclass doesn't own this object. You need to assign a subclass of UIButton to make an outlet, or use parent ViewController class, that own all the subviews

Comment: I see. I was hoping to keep the UIButton code within the proper UIView subclass

Answer (score 1):

There is some conditions for this can happen!
Sometimes, you can not added IBOutlet to swift file
Such as, You have tableview and it has header view!
That headerview subclassed and you can not add IBOulet to this subclass
But You can add in ViewController Class that is connect storyboard.